# Python print complete output of a classifier (like Jupyter) in Spyder

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

Now I discovered why Jupyter is better compared to the Spyder. However, I would continue to use Spyder IDE, not interested to change the IDE now. I have an interesting situation. I found that Jupyter prints complete function output but not Spyder. How do I get similar output in Spyder.

Expected output in the Spyder (below is Jupyter output):
[image]

Present output in the Spyder:

[image]

The spyder is simply reproducing what I had entered. How do I make it display the additional information that Jupyter is showing? or is it that not possible in Spyder IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the IPython console that Spyder uses would be different from the Jupyter notebook, given the same versions of scikit-learn. However, it looks like what you are after is the parameter values that you more conviently can access (or just print) with `get_params()` method, e.g. `clf_entropy.get_params()`.